# Issue ploting WindRose using WINDROSE doc

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, rose-plot, windrose

I'm trying to **plot the windrose** using a set of monthly (2 years) wind data from era5 **for a fixed coordinate** (a point, latlon)... I transformed the data into a DataFrame (with columns: Datetime; direction; speed) but when I try to plot I get the following error message (below):

[image: error mensage]

Using the [WindRoseDoc](https://windrose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

I have imported:

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes;
ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax(), and I have tried plot;
ax.bar(wind_df.direction, wind_df.speed, opening=0.8)
```

I expected to see the rose of the wind. But all I got was the error message: ValueError: 'Fire' is not a valid value for name; supported values are '538', 'accent', etc...

[image: empty plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems similar to [this issue](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/5287) here on a different repo, unfortunately it is unanswered. Make sure your versions of Windrose and Matplotlib are compatible...

Windrose 1.8.1 requires matplotlib >= 3

The issue seems to come from [this matplotlib function](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/370547ebfc12e879aefe0f914eaa94d72eb95a9b/lib/matplotlib/_api/__init__.py#L101), which in this instance *might* be checking a list of available colourmaps, python proplot mentions 'Fire' which is not in the matplotlib.cm list... but both matplotlib and proplot should be implementing case insensitive checks on the list you have starting with '538'

Have you tried explicitly setting the cmap when plotting like...

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm

ax.bar(wind_df.direction, wind_df.speed, opening=0.8, cmap = cm.tab10)
```